# Set Git globals

Tags: git, git-config

I'm constantly using the same git aliases (as I'm sure most are). I would like to use aliases like `gs` for `git status` and `ga.` for `git add .`. I know I can set them per repository like this `alias gs='git status'`. How can I add this to my `.gitconfig` file so these are globally set? I this currently in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]    
    s = status
    a = add
```

But when I try to run `gs`, I get `zsh: command not found: 'git`.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) you can add them to the configuration file in your home directory `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: @fredrik `.gitconfig` is only for git aliases. Not the type of aliases OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases should under the `[alias]` section. For example:

```
 [alias]
     s = status
     a = add
     tg = tag -l --sort=version:refname
```

If you want to set `g` as the `git` alias (I wouldn't recommend that), you should set it in your startup file (e.g.  `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, ..).

Answer (score 3):

> I know I can set them per repository like this `alias gs='git status'`.

That's not a git alias at all! That's a shell alias. You put that in your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` or whatever corresponds to your shell) and it will be available in all new shells you start. That's it.

A git alias will always be called as `git` , so `git a` etc. Not `ga`. Git can't do that, because it only has control over the subcommands.

Answer (score 1):

Add them to your global .gitconfig

```
git config --global alias.gs 'status'
git gs
```